# Using RFQ form in blank theme

Tags: orocommerce

We are trying to set up out own custom theme based on the blank theme.

The request for quote form does not work.

To see if it was something we did I have downloaded the virtual box version of orocommercer V4.2.1-499

When I use the default and custom theme everything seems fine but when I use the blank theme (which our theme is based on) apart form the my profile page the customer pages do not work.

It shows the links but nothing in the main body.

In the two images the only change between them was changing the theme from blank to custom.

Is there something missing from the blank theme that we need to add in to get those tabs to work?
[image: RFQ in blank theme]

[image: RFQ in custom theme]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The `blank` theme does not have full functionality as `default` or `custom` themes.
As I see, the [RFQ form](https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/tree/master/src/Oro/Bundle/ProductBundle/Resources/views/layouts/default/oro_product_frontend_quick_add) is defined in default theme.

The solution might be to copy all code that you need (JS, CSS, html, twig) from a `default` theme to your new own theme.

Comment: In the documentation it says to use the blank theme as the base when crating your own theme.  Is there a list of items that need copying to make it fully functioning?